# Make sense of the tensor product $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/4}\mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Suppose $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/4$-module, how do we make sense of the tensor  product $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/4}\mathbb{Z}/2$? Do we look at $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as $\mathbb{Z}/4\bigg /2\mathbb{Z}/4 $ which is a $\mathbb{Z}/4$-module?

Comment: Yes, that is what we do.

Comment: To go further, this allows us to say $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/4}\mathbb{Z}/2$ is isomorphic to $M/2M$.